# Core Data NSManagedObject - tracking if attribute was changed

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an object - `Config`.  I want to know if the `Account` attribute on `Config` has changed.  When this happens, I want to send a `NSNotification` so that all code that cares about when the `Account` changes will know.  My initial thought was in my `NSManagedObject` subclass that I would override the `setAccount` method to set a transient attribute `AccountDidChange` to `true`.  Then in `didSave` if `AccountDidChange` was `true` I would send the notification and then set it back to `false`.  Is there a better way?  My issue though is that from what I've read, by changing `AccountDidChange` back to `false`, I would have dirtied my object and need to save again.

A little more info:
The `Config` object is the current configuration of the application.  `Account` could actually be changed to `ActiveAccount`.  There is a relationship to the `Account` Entity that has a list of all Accounts. The idea is that the user can change the active account of the application.  So we have a set of servers and the user can only be logged into one at a time.  `Config.Account` points to that active account and it is used to setup connections to the server to retrieve information.  I am using this notification that `Config.Account` has changed to tell other objects to clean up their information - like list of alerts.  Basically, all information is per Account so it needs to be removed and then refetched on its next load with the new active account.

Also, the given names are not my actual object names - just trying to make the example easier to follow.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at KVO (Key-Value Observing): [Key-Value Observing Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVOBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20002252-178352). That's the standard way to do this in Cocoa, and is a fundamental technology that you need to understand to be a good Cocoa programmer.

KVO will let objects that care about changes to the `Account` property (which you should probably name `account`, not `Account`) register to be notified when the property is changed. KVO will "just work" for standard NSManagedObjects, without any additional work on your part.

The relevant methods are as follows:

- `-addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:` which you call on your Config object to set up the observation
- `-observeValueForKeyPath:ofObject:change:context:` which will be called on the observer object anytime an observed value is changed
- `-removeObserver:forKeyPath:` which you need to make sure you call when the observer no longer needs change notifications (including before the observer is deallocated).

This is all described in a lot more detail in the linked documentation.

EDIT BELOW:

Without knowing anything about your application, it's hard to know why you'd want to be notified only upon save. NSManagedObjectContext posts NSManagedObjectContextWillSaveNotification and NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification. The notification's userInfo has arrays containing inserted, updated and deleted objects, but the notifications aren't as fine-grained as individual properties. I suppose you could manually keep track of changed accounts between didSave notifications. That'll probably get inefficient if you have lots of Configs in your store.

Changes to NSManagedObjects are immediate, they're just not saved to the persistent store until you call `save:` on the managed object context. Perhaps if you explain more about exactly what you're trying to accomplish and why, I can better help.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, then observeValueForKeyPath... will be called when Account is changed - not just when it is saved.  I guess I should have been more specific that I want to know when it is actually saved to the store.  Also, perhaps I have a second issue - which is not fully understanding when/how to save changes.  Even though I change the value of my Config's Account, it isn't really changed until it is saved.  Perhaps the changing and saving should happen on a second context and then be merged into the main application context.  This is still all new to me but thank you.

Comment: I still don't understand why you only want to be notified on save instead of when the active account is changed. However, since there's apparently only one Config object in the application, it's easy enough to keep track of changes to it in your application controller (or where ever makes the most sense) and post a notification in the managed object context's NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification if the active account has changed since the last save.

Comment: It could be my lack of experience with Core Data that makes me want to wait for save. I feel that if that value hasn't been saved then nothing has been validated so it isn't in its final state.  I am currently sending the notification after the save is successful in my controller. I thought that it would be nice to wrap it into the NSMangedObject so that if other code were to change the active account it would not have to worry about sending the notification. I know that this change would not be rolled back before a commit but this generalization wouldn't always work. Thanks-I'll keep thinking