# Tracking model object attributes changes (dirty) in Cocoa

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, cocoa, core-data

I'm trying to gain insight into the least overhead solution to tracking model object changes in Cocoa.

As I see it there are 3 options:

1. Use Core Data – lot's of functionality exists for monitoring model object changes ([Core Data NSManagedObject - tracking if attribute was changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298461/core-data-nsmanagedobject-tracking-if-attribute-was-changed)).  I don't know what the overhead of Core Data's management infrastructure is compared to other approaches but it's well established architecture for multi-threading support is a plus.  For cross-platform devs there is some downside in not having a readily accessible schema but there are ways around that issue.
2. Write custom accessors that mark the object as dirty when updating a field with a new value.  I've been using this technique with mixed success for quite some time.  There are some sticky issues to deal with when sharing objects across threads.  You also don't get the benefits of enhancements to automatic synthesis of attributes, etc.  You do, however, have greater control of your data store than when using Core Data which can be of benefit (eg. certain operations can be done in a SQL store across many objects in a much more efficient way). Note: There could be a lot of variation here depending on how you write the accessors.  For the sake of conversation let's assume setters make a check of the new value against the old one, make appropriate calls to KVO (willChange / didChange), and set a boolean flag (all within synchronization of course).
3. Use KVO to monitor object fields (ala keyPathsForValuesAffectingValueForKey:) and mark the object as dirty in the KVO callout.  I have yet to use this method but it seems like a decent approach.  The obvious downside would be the callout every time a setter is called.

I am inclined to think that option 2 has the lowest overhead (in terms of raw processing requirements) given that Core Data and KVO both have some additional overhead either in the generated accessors or in the KVO callouts.  The question is, how substantial is the overhead?

And lastly, did I miss an option?

Thanks.

Comment: Core Data's `NSManagedObjectContext`, in my opinion, makes tracking changes to an `NSManagedObject` very simple.

Comment: True but the question is what the overhead of this "simplicity" is when compared to other approaches.